# Infer parameter pack types from pack of template types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-functions

Is it possible to pass a parameter pack of template types, and infer a parameter pack from the template types stored type.

E.g. I have a function foo which returns a tuple which holds parameters `A...`. If the function accepts a parameter pack of vectors `B...` which store the types to be found in `A...`, can these be inferred somehow from `A...` alone? Or must they always be explicitly specified?

```
template <typename A..., typename B...>
std::tuple<B...> foo(A...)
{
    ...
}

std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<char> b;
std::vector<std::string> c;
auto bar = foo<int, char, std::string>(a, b, c); // Works
auto bar = foo(a, b, c); // Will not work because B... can't be inferred yet.
```

Additionally, I can implement the constraint that all types within `A...` must be `std::vector`s via a `static_assert` but I can imagine there is a neater way using template types. Please could you also suggest such a method if one exists?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason against return type deduction? Why not something like `auto foo(A... as) { return std::make_tuple(as...); }`

Comment: If the types are required to be known prior to actually constructing the tuple. Though I realise in this example that is not the case.

Comment: This code does not compile. What is the expected tuple in your example?

Comment: A tuple containing the first element of each vector passed to foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the type to be infered not deduce with an auto return type

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> foo(const std::vector<Ts>& ... Vec)
{
    return std::make_tuple(Vec[0]...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise that the pack could be expanded in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account provided example and clarifying comment ("function should return a tuple of a first elements to each vector"), the trailing return type will do the job, if for whatever reason fully `auto`matic return type deduction is not desired:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<class... ARG> auto foo(ARG... ) -> std::tuple<typename ARG::value_type...>;

auto bar() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<bool> b;
    std::vector<char* > c;
    return foo(a, b, c);
}
```